# Are files ".cls-meta.xml " deployed through change sets when I deploy .cls file?

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata, change-set

I did a change in a metadata of a class (ClassName.cls-meta.xml)
If I would deploy ClassName.cls apex class through change sets, then file ClassName.cls-meta.xml would be deployed also?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as you have push your changes to the source org, whenever you create a new change set, the configuration file will be included. for example, that's one way you deactivate triggers in a production org. you edit the `trigger-meta.xml` file, as explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327373&type=1)